# filter clause syntax for mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL 8.0

I've recent read a blog https://medium.com/swlh/three-useful-yet-neglected-sql-statements-9406d9316e10 that talks about creating pivot table using `FILTER` function, I followed exact step and tried it out on my database however it keeps on giving me syntax error.

What is the correct syntax for using filter clause in MySQL?

My current query:

```
  select date(time) as dt
      , count(*) FILTER (where type= 'A') as 'B'
      , count(*) filter (where type = 'B') as 'B'
      , count(*) filter (where type = 'C') as 'C'
  from table
group by dt;
```

not sure why this is giving me an error.

It works when I use Case When to create pivot table

```
 select date(start_time) as dt
      , sum(case when type = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as 'A'
      , sum(case when type = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as 'B'
      , sum(case when type = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as 'C'
  from table
group by dt;
```

How can I do this using Filter clause in mysql or is there Filter function in MySql?

Comment: Are you sure MySQL has `FILTER` function? Even though the article is talking about `SQL`, it doesn't necessarily meant for `MySQL`. It could be for `MSSQL` or `PostgreSQL`.

Comment: I am unsure... but when I type `filter` it is marked as a function

Comment: i donot think mysql supports it yet

Comment: Do u know why it is marked as a function though? in workbench it turns blue when I type `filter` is it used in different way? I'm curious to know

Comment: Not sure why but I'm using SQLyog tool and it doesn't recognize filter as a function.

Comment: Ensure - FILTER function is **NOT** listed in [MySQL SQL Function and Operator Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-function-reference.html). I think that the article author tells about PostgreSQL or some another DBMS.

Comment: Yes, I've read throught MySQL doc and couldn't find filter function however since `filter` was marked blue like any other function in MySQL I thought it does something.

Answer (score 1):

MySql doesn't support filter clause - you can try the below -

```
select date(start_time) as dt
      , sum(type = 'A') as 'A'
      , sum(type = 'B') as 'B'
      , sum(type = 'C') as 'C'
  from table
group by dt
```

Comment: Thanks! this seems more cleaner than using case when. Is there any downside of this? Why would someone use case when over this

Comment: @Ambleu If there is no value with any condition it will return null instead of 0

Comment: Maybe `SUM(IFNULL(type  = 'A',0))` to take care of the `NULL`?

Comment: One downside is that this isn't portable, while `case` is ANSI SQL and portable.